# UITableView reloading the data partially with core data

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview

When using reloading with indexpaths or indexsets the _recordLabel and _dateLabel are shown, and then not shown, and it repeats again. Im using the debug paint layers and its nowhere around. But if use reload data everything seems fine. I don't know why is that happening.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier;
    cellIdentifier = [_sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];


    XFitGroupCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[XFitGroupCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        [self stampCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)stampCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"exerciseDescriptionCell"]) {

        if (!_textView) {
            _textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 22.f, cell.frame.size.width, 66.f)];
        }
        _textView.editable = NO;
        _textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:14.f];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:_textView];

    }
    else if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"exerciseResultsCell"]) {

        UILabel *recordLabelTag = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.f, 28.f, 55.f, 14.f)];

        if ([_exercise.eType.name isEqualToString:@"Strength"]) {
            recordLabelTag.text = @"PR";
        }
        else {
            recordLabelTag.text = @"UB";
        }

        recordLabelTag.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Heavy" size:14.f];
        recordLabelTag.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:recordLabelTag];

        if (!_recordLabel) {
            _recordLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.f, 48.f, 55.f, 12.f)];
        }
        _recordLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:12.f];
        _recordLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:_recordLabel];

        UILabel *dateLabelTag = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.f, 28.f, 55.f, 14.f)];
        dateLabelTag.text = @"Date";
        dateLabelTag.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Heavy" size:14.f];
        dateLabelTag.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:dateLabelTag];

        if (!_dateLabel) {
            _dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.f, 48.f, 55.f, 12.f)];
        }
        _dateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:12.f];
        _dateLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:_dateLabel];

        UIButton *recordButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - 73.f, 30.f, 65.f, 28.f)];
        recordButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:77.f/255.f green:123.f/255.f blue:209.f/255.f alpha:1.f];
        recordButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.f;
        [recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addRecord) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:recordButton];

        UILabel *newPRLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.f, 7.f, 55.f, 14.f)];

        if ([_exercise.eType.name isEqualToString:@"Strength"]) {
            newPRLabel.text = @"New PR";
        }
        else {
            newPRLabel.text = @"New UB";
        }

        newPRLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        newPRLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Book" size:14.f];
        [recordButton addSubview:newPRLabel];

        UIButton *showAllButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - 73.f - 75.f, 30.f, 65.f, 28.f)];
        showAllButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:98.f/255.f green:233.f/255.f blue:126.f/255.f alpha:1.f];
        showAllButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.f;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:showAllButton];

        UILabel *showAllLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.f, 7.f, 55.f, 14.f)];
        showAllLabel.text = @"Show All";
        showAllLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        showAllLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Book" size:14.f];
        [showAllButton addSubview:showAllLabel];

    }
}


- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"exerciseDescriptionCell"]) {
        [(XFitGroupCell *)cell setText:@"Description"];
        [(XFitGroupCell *)cell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"descriptionIcon"]];

        _textView.text = _exercise.overview;

    }
    else if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"exerciseResultsCell"]) {
        [(XFitGroupCell *)cell setText:@"Previous Results"];
        [(XFitGroupCell *)cell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"recordIcon"]];

        ExerciseRecord *personalRecord = _exercise.personalRecord;

        NSLog(@"Received: %@\n", personalRecord.score);
        _recordLabel.text = [personalRecord.score stringValue];
        NSLog(@"Text : %@\n", _recordLabel.text);
        _dateLabel.text = [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:personalRecord.date];
    }
}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        return 88.f;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        return 66.f;
    }
    return 0.f;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 15.f;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 7.f;
}

#pragma mark - UIAlertViewDelegate

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 1) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            ExerciseRecord *eRecord = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ExerciseRecord" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

            eRecord.score = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text intValue]];
            eRecord.date = [NSDate date];
            eRecord.exercise = _exercise;

            NSError *error;
            if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"%@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }



    [_tableView reloadData];
//[_tableView beginUpdates];
                //[_tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                //[_tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
//[_tableView endUpdates];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this isn't working, but from my experience I'd recommend you use a framework while working with Core Data instead of doing all the work manually yourself. I personally use the Sensible TableView framework, which automatically fetches my data and displays it in table views. It also handles all entity relationships and auto creates the detail views for them. Saves me tons of development time when working on Core Data projects. HTH.